# Can weakpointer be a substitute for mutex or critical section in synchronization issues

Tags: c++

I would like to know if Weak Pointers can be used against/instead of Mutex/Critical Sections for synchronization issues.

Comment: no, how would that even work?

Comment: No. What gave you the idea that weak pointers had anything to do with synchronization?

Comment: Show some code to demonstrate what kind of synchronization you mean.

Comment: Like, do you mean just: does promoting weak_ptr to shared_ptr need mutex, or are you asking something broader?

Answer (score 2):

If the *only* synchronisation issue you've got is ensuring the object's still around when you'd like to access it, then getting a `shared_ptr` from a `weak_ptr` will ensure its lifetime is extended.  It's only sufficient for very narrow scenarios though, for example - if a `shared_ptr` is stored in a container somewhere, and may be erased at any time but is otherwise unused, while your code with the `weak_ptr` may want to actually access or modify the data content of the object.

If you also need to protect against concurrent accesses during updates to the data in the object, then you need more than that `shared_ptr`....